# How can I make this low-poly curve look more round without more subdivisions?

Tags: edges, normals, topology, smooth

Sorry if this sounds like a dumb question. I've been up all night working, and my brain is mush.
So I am modeling a low poly object I am having trouble making a curved edge look more smooth.
Since it's low poly, I'm obviously getting these jagged edges.

[image]

I was wondering if there is any way I can make this look more round without adding more geometry???

I tried baking a high poly mesh to a low poly one, adding a Data Transfer modifier, Normal Edit modifier, and Weighted Normal modifier, and using loop tools. But I can't seem to smooth out this pesky curve.

Here is a link to a copy of the [project file](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mtdhhgf862adv0i/AABKpO_It53vk7V9x5xDe8gQa?dl=0).

Comment: I'm afraid you have no other choice but to subdivide, data trasfer will only affect the shading, not the contour of your object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have no other choice but to subdivide, *Data Trasfer* will only affect the shading, not the contour of your object.

Comment: Right on :/
Thanks!